# C++ type casting. When will static_cast succeed and reinterpret_cast will cause an issue?

Tags: c++, casting

I understand that a `static_cast` is a cast from one type to another that (intuitively) is a cast that could under some circumstance succeed and be meaningful in the absence of a dangerous cast. Meanwhile, a `reinterpret_cast` is a cast that represents an unsafe conversion that might reinterpret the bits of one value as the bits of another value.

Can someone describe a scenario when the code will compile, cast and `static_cast` will cause no issue, but with `reinterpret_cast` there will be an issue?

Comment: Any `reinterpret_cast` that is not specifically listed as having well-defined results in the Standard might cause problems, and at least makes the program formally ill-formed.

Comment: Casting to  base class with multiple inheritance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This will do it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct C{int n;};
struct A{int n;};
struct B : A, C{};

int main()
{
    B b;
    B* pb = &b;
    cout << static_cast<C*>(pb) << "\n";
    cout << reinterpret_cast<C*>(pb);
}
```

Note the differences in the two addresses.

I've built some multiple inheritance here, and have put an explicit member in the base classes, in order to circumvent possible optimisation of empty base classes to size zero.

See https://ideone.com/QLvBku

Comment: Note: without multi-inheritance, a base class without virtual methods and a derived class with a virtual method will generate an offset of "v-ptr" size (plus potential padding).

Answer (score 16):

The simplest such case is `reinterpret_cast<void*>(NULL)`, which may yield a non-null pointer.

By contrast, `static_cast<void*>(NULL)` is safe because it is required to yield a null pointer.

Why? `NULL` is an integer constant equal to 0. `static_cast` requires that 0 be converted to an appropriate null pointer, but `reinterpret_cast` does not have this same requirement. If the internal representation of a null pointer isn't the same as that of integer zero, then the results will be different. This type of breakage would be most likely on architectures with segmented addressing.

Comment: I find this surprising. Can you further expand how/why `reinterpret_cast<void*>(NULL)` might return non-null?

Comment: CPP Reference for `reinterpret_cast` says "*The null pointer constant `NULL` or integer zero is not guaranteed to yield the null pointer value of the target type; `static_cast` or implicit conversion should be used for this purpose.*"

Answer (score 9):

One of such cases is multiple inheritance - `static_cast` does adjustment of the address (so the address of the base object pointer after the cast can be different from the derived object address, to point to the correct base class items).

`reinterpret_cast` does not do any address adjustments, so the cast to base class might use a wrong address (i.e. always returns the address of the derived object unchanged).